# Querying multiple values, each with their own time span, in HIVE

Tags: sql, string, datetime, hive, where-clause

I want to select all devices from a table that fit into a list of possible values. I can use RLIKE as such:

```
select * from table where device_id RLIKE 'xx200|xx202|xx403|xx770|xx309|xx931|'
```

But I also want to select a time range, and the time range is *different* for each device_id.

How can this be accomplished in a single query?

If I do:

```
select * from table WHERE timestamp >= '2010-09-01' AND timestamp <= '2013-08-31' AND where device_id RLIKE 'xx200|xx202|xx403|xx770|xx309|xx931|'
```

...obviously this won't work since I only provide a single range of timestamps.

Answer (score 0):

Then you will have to break the regexp, and explictely enumerate the pairs of range/string conditions, as in:

```
SELECT *
FROM mytable
WHERE 
    (
        timestamp >= '2010-09-01' AND timestamp <= '2013-08-31' -- first range
        AND device_id LIKE '%xx200%'                            -- first string
    ) OR (
        timestamp >= '2010-10-01' AND timestamp <= '2013-09-31' -- second range
        AND device_id LIKE '%x403%'                             -- second string
    ) OR ...
```